# Power Query - Repeat rows for each month

Tags: powerquery

I'm a beginner in Power Query and I have some data that that I want to repeat for each end of month to show a running total.

I can get the running total every time there's a transaction but how do I show a running total by month even if there are no transactions in that month?

[image: Example of expected result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can merge the original table to a date table. Since you can do a running total if you were to just use amounts of 0 on days where there was no data (Find and replace nulls with 0) then you should be golden from there.